# Async Javascript callback not triggering the RaiseCallBackEvent function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, sharepoint, callback

In my asp.net application I used the async javascript callback.
 The requirement is once the user enters the Postal code an async javascript callback function should be called. And the server side code must return me the **city** with respect to the **postal code**.

The coding I did is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPostCode" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" onchange="javascript: getCityAndStreet();" BorderStyle="Ridge" Height="20px" style="margin-left: 10px" Width="442px"></asp:TextBox>
```

This textbox `onchange` it will call the javascript `function getCityAndStreet()`

```
function getCityAndStreet()
{
    var postalCode = document.getElementById('<%=txtPostCode.ClientID%>');
    CallServer(postalCode.value, "");
}

function ReceiveCityAndStreet(rValue,context)
{
    alert(rValue);

    var city = document.getElementById('<%= txtCity.ClientID%>');
    city.value = rValue;
}
```

Here the **CallServer** is the server side runtime javascript which is registered as below

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String cbReference = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "ReceiveCityAndStreet", "context",true);

    String callbackScript;
    callbackScript = "function CallServer(arg, context)" +   "{ " + "alert('Entered inside CallServer' + arg);" + cbReference + ";}";

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CallServer", callbackScript, true);
}
```

I implemented the `ICallBackHandler` and by this I got 2 methods:

```
string ICallbackEventHandler.GetCallbackResult()
{
    return cityAndStreet;
}

void ICallbackEventHandler.RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    txtStreet.Enabled = true;
    txtCity.Enabled = true;

    cityAndStreet = eventArgument;
}
```

in page_load function I just disabled the `txtStreet.Enabled`. `txtCity.Enabled` text boxes and on the raise callbackevent I am enabling it.

The issue here is the `RaiseCallBackEvent` is not working. I mean its not been triggered implicitly.

(This application is not accessed directly in the browser it is accessed through the SharePoint site)

Comment: This is quite complex to get the async call results and getting more complex when you have many calls, try using jQuery ajax

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your button actually does postback when you click on it. You do not need postback because you are calling server using AJAX. Try changing onchage handler to this:

```
onchange="getCityAndStreet();return false;"
```

This will cause your button not to trigger postback.

EDIT: Also i want to mention that you cannot change controls in RaiseCallBackEvent method. It is not an actual postback. You need to enable text fields using javascript in onSuccess method.